# Tapestry: custom component and title in Grid header

Tags: grid, custom-component, tapestry

I need to change the title of a grid header, and add a custom component to it. I use a .properties file to set the title, and this template code to add the custom component:

```
<table class="table table-striped" t:type="grid" t:source="data" t:rowsPerPage="50" t:pagerPosition="bottom">

    <p:specialHeader>
        <t:tooltip tip="tipData"></t:tooltip>
    </p:specialHeader>

</table>
```

When viewing the grid in a browser, the component appears but there is no title.

If I set a title in the template, like so, then it loses the sort functionality:

```
    <p:specialHeader>Title
        <t:tooltip tip="tipData"></t:tooltip>
    </p:specialHeader>
```

How can I get the title, sort and custom component to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said [here](http://apache-tapestry-mailing-list-archives.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Sort-functionality-in-custom-Grid-headers-td5721699.html) you can't combine the default header block and your own custom header block, it's either one or the other.

I think you're best bet is a [mixin](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-mixins.html). Take a look at Taha's blog post [here](http://tawus.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/tapestry-mixins-classtransformations/) where he creates a HelpText mixin which applies to a Label component. His mixin looks at the message catalog for a "propertyName-help" entry and adds a "title" attribute to the DOM. The blog post takes it one step further and uses a ComponentClassTransformWorker2 to atach the HelpText mixin to every label (even the ones inside the BeanEditor component).

You could do the same thing but you would create a mixin for either [Grid](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html) or [GridColumns](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/GridColumns.html) (Grid delegates to GridColumns to draw the headers). If you'd like some examples of Grid mixins, take a look at my tapestry-stitch demo's [here](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/griddecoratordemo) and [here](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com//gridcollapsedemo).

So, you won't be reusing the tooltip component, you will be copying the behaviour. This will most likely involve adding a "data-tooltip" attribute to the `th` DOM elements serverside. You can then fire some javascript on the client to find all elements with a "data-tooltip" attribute and do some UI magic.